# Use of PowerShell commandlets without any parameter

Tags: command-line, powershell

As stated [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847867.aspx) in a PowerShell help's syntax:

> Parameters can be mandatory or optional. In a syntax diagram, optional
>       items are enclosed in brackets ([ ]).

So in a command like `Set-NetIPAddress` as stated:

```
NAME
    Set-NetIPAddress

SYNOPSIS
    Modifies the configuration of an IP address.


SYNTAX
    Set-NetIPAddress [[-IPAddress] [<String[]>]] [-AddressFamily [<AddressFamily[]>]] [-AddressState
    [<AddressState[]>]] [-CimSession [<CimSession[]>]] [-IncludeAllCompartments] [-InterfaceAlias [<String[]>]]
    [-InterfaceIndex [<UInt32[]>]] [-PassThru] [-PolicyStore [<String>]] [-PreferredLifetime [<TimeSpan>]]
    [-PrefixLength [<Byte>]] [-PrefixOrigin [<PrefixOrigin[]>]] [-SkipAsSource [<Boolean>]] [-SuffixOrigin
    [<SuffixOrigin[]>]] [-ThrottleLimit [<Int32>]] [-Type [<Type[]>]] [-ValidLifetime [<TimeSpan>]] [-Confirm]
    [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]

    Set-NetIPAddress [-CimSession [<CimSession[]>]] [-PassThru] [-PreferredLifetime [<TimeSpan>]] [-PrefixLength
    [<Byte>]] [-SkipAsSource [<Boolean>]] [-ThrottleLimit [<Int32>]] [-ValidLifetime [<TimeSpan>]] [-Confirm]
    [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

there is no necessary parameters but what is the use of running this command and many others without any parameters while running that have no obvious result just going a to a new prompt?

Comment: As it is a `Set-*` cmdlet there isn't any reason to run it without any parameters. But what's your actual question? The logic for the `Set-NetIPAddress` is probably that you didn't want to change anything and as such everything was successful. What output did you expect?

Comment: I am just curious about it.Also I remember there was a command that has no necessary parameter in syntax but running it without any parameter throw an error .I couldn't remember that now.

Comment: You won't find a universal answer to this as it depends on the person that wrote the cmdlet. A lot of cmdlets that require a set of parameters will just ask your for them if you don't provide those parameters (as long as they're called standalone). At least that's my experience.

Comment: `-InputObject` is necessary for `set-netipaddress` as seen when running `get-help set-netipaddress -full`

Comment: if it were necessary an error message should be returned when using without any parameter.

Comment: well it does return an error message on my computer if i run it without parameters

Comment: There simply are no mandatory parameters for the command. All available parameters happen to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. I'm guessing, like most PowerShell cmdlets, you're able to pass some of those values on the pipeline (ie. piped from another command prior to this one - `'192.168.1.3' | Set-NetIPAddress`).  In which case there would be no parameters provided in the traditional sense of the word.
2. I think what you're seeing might be a limitation in the PowerShell syntax diagrams.  I'm guessing you would have to provide at least one of those parameters, but no one in particular is required which makes them all "optional" in a sense.